# delete a record from phpadmin

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a list of rows with corresponding delete buttons. When the user clicks the delete button that row must be removed.

my html button as part of my table. I have checked that the correct ID is passed to the function.

```
 <td style="border-color: #f3e0d7" ><button  name="btn_delete" class="deleteSub" onclick="DeleteSubscription('.$row["RSS_ID"].')" >Delete</button></td>
```

javascript for the DeleteSubscription button

```
function DeleteSubscription(id){

alert(id);

if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this subscription?")){
    $.ajax({
        url:'LandingPage.php',
        method:"POST",
        date:
            {
                delete_Subscription:1,
                idPHP:id,
            },
        success:function(response){
            alert(response);
            fetch_data();
        },
        dataType:"text",
    });
}
};
```

my PHP code for communicating with the table

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_Subscription'])){

$ID = !empty($_POST['idPHP']) ? trim($_POST['idPHP']) : null;

try{
    $connect = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);

    $sql=("DELETE FROM rssfeeds WHERE RSS_ID='".$ID."'");

    if(mysqli_query($connect,$sql)){
        exit('Subscription deleted');
    }
    else{
        print_r($sql->errorInfo());
        exit('error');
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    console.log($e);
}
}
```

Comment: Nothing. my response alert from success function is blank... Nothing is showing in the console either

Comment: It's just localhost. I have another dozen or so ajax statements pointing to that php url and they are working. Is there any other info that can help resolve this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be data instead of date?